# Difference between ssh and scp command

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I am playing with overthewire's bandit wargame. In Level 18, the bashrc file is configured in such a way that, it will immediately log out users who try to log in, after verifying password of-course. 
For example:

```
ssh bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220
```

does not work. Users will be immediately logout. So, I tried with scp, the password is incorrect.

```
scp bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org:2220/home/bandit18/readme .
```

Even though I manage to successfully log in using the password I have. Finally the following command works, I don't know about this either.

```
ssh bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220 "cat ~/readme"
```

How come, "cat ˜/readme" does the trick, read the file without login or whats procedure here?

So my questions are: 
1) How come the same password is valid for ssh but not for scp?
2) How come ssh does not work, but ssh with the cat command specified works?

Thanks.

PS: If any wants here's the password: `kfBf3eYk5BPBRzwjqutbbfE887SVc5Yd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. scp is working: `scp -P 2220 bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org:/home/bandit18/readme .`
2. .bashrc contains `exit 0` so bash exited immediately after you login via ssh:

   ```
   > ssh bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220 "tail -n 2 .bashrc"
   This is a OverTheWire game server. More information on http://www.overthewire.org/wargames

   bandit18@bandit.labs.overthewire.org's password: 
   echo 'Byebye !'
   exit 0
   ```